# If false, do nothing?

Tags: excel, vba, formulas

I'm attempting to make an excel formula do nothing if a cell is blank, is this possible?

This is the formula as it stands, could I nest an if statement that checks if F4 & G4 are blank and if they are it doesn't perform this formula?

```
=IF(F4 < G4, G4 - F4, TODAY() - F4)
```

...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=IF(F4&G4="","",IF(F4<G4,G4-F4,TODAY()-F4))`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

```
=IF(F4 = "", "", IF(F4 < G4, G4 - F4, TODAY() - F4))
```

Woooooohoooooo

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `=IF(A1="M", "MALE", IF(A1="F", "FEMALE", "N/A"))`  Unfortunately, it's a bit verbose, but it will do what you need.

I hope this helps.

Josh